# How to Properly merge 2 JS Objects on a single property

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 3 JSON files. Lets call them file1.json , file2.json and file3.json.

They all look very similar and are in this structure:

```
"orgItems":[...]
```

There is a top level `orgItems` property. Now what I'm struggling with is that these are 3 large files. Almost 20-30mb each. I want to concatenate all of these into 1 file.

Whats the best way to do this ? To be able to grab the orgItems object out of each of the 3 files and then have it all in one object in one file. So I just want one file `combinedResponses.json` and that should have

```
combinedResponses.json
"orgItems":[...file1.orgItems,...file2.orgItems,...file3.orgItems]
```

Comment: so,what is the issue??

Comment: the issue is the file isn't being created. Im using fs to write to an output file but it always errors out. The original object always gets overwritten. Sorry should've specified that.

Comment: Please post your code ,where you are facing issue

Comment: Is the value of orgItems an array? Or is it a nested object?

Comment: orgItems is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JSONStream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONStream). It provides an easy way to stream json files (so you don't have to load it all into memory at once) and receive events for matching paths. You could pipe the input stream to an output stream that writes the concatenated file.

This is a bit outside my wheelhouse and I'm sure it could be improved, but I think something like this does what you want. You could tweak the `JSONStream.parse` argument to get only the objects you care about.

```
const JSONStream = require('JSONStream');
const fs = require('fs');

function appendData (sourceFile, outputStream) {
    const file = fs.createReadStream(sourceFile);
    const jsonStream = JSONStream.parse('*');

    jsonStream.on('data', data => outputStream.write(JSON.stringify(data)));

    file.pipe(jsonStream);

    file.on('end', () => {
        file.close();
    });
}

const out = fs.createWriteStream('data/concatted.json', {autoClose: true});
appendData('data/data-1.json', out);
appendData('data/data-2.json', out);
appendData('data/data-3.json', out);
```

Comment: I think this might be it. Unfortunately I won't be able to try it out till monday, but I'll get back to your answer. Appreicate the help :D